# Black cherry tree suddenly producing berries after 20yrs

Tags: trees

We’ve had a very large black cherry tree in our backyard for the past 20 years. It has never produced berries until this year. Does anyone know if that is normal for this type of tree?

Comment: Could be a neighbor recently planted a pollinator a block away.